# Converting a set of .bib entries in bibitem

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a set of bibtex items:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{citation1, 
author={authors...}, 
booktitle={Computer Vision Workshops (ICCVW), 2013 IEEE International Conference on}, 
title={title...}, 
year={2013}, 
month={Dec}, 
pages={145-152}, 
doi={10.1109/ICCVW.2013.25},}

  @INPROCEEDINGS{citation2, 
author={authors...}, 
booktitle={Computer Vision Workshops (ICCVW), 2013 IEEE International Conference on}, 
title={title...}, 
year={2013}, 
month={Dec}, 
pages={145-152}, 
doi={10.1109/ICCVW.2013.25},}
```

Is there any tools/commands to convert all of these to (or any other bibitem style):

```
\bibitem{citation1} Authors (years). \emph{title}.
\bibitem{citation1} Authors (years). \emph{title}.
...
```

?

PS. I mainly use sharelatex.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical use is to include

```
\bibliographystyle{<style>}
\bibliography{<bibtex-file>}
```

in your latex code, and then run `(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex -> (pdf)latex`.

Running `bibtex` generates a file with a `bbl` extension where you can find `\bibitem`.  The format of `\bibitem`s depends on the selected `<style>`.

Answer (score 3):

if you use ShareLatex. Next to recompile button, there is "Logs and output files" click on it and scroll down. Then click on "Other logs & files" here is your BBL file